# Blocking Bittorrent using Netgear DG834GV doesn't seem to be working

Tags: firewall, access-control

I'm trying to control access to BitTorrent in my network.  Presumably the best way to do this is using the router, a Netgear DG834GV.

I've set up a custom service that covers TCP ports 6881 - 6999 (port numbers from [here](http://btfaq.com/serve/cache/25.html)).  I've set up an Outbound Services filter that says "Block always".

[image]

Yet when I then start my test torrent (http://releases.ubuntu.com/9.10/ubuntu-9.10-server-i386.iso.torrent), the system is downloading the file regardless.

Is there some terribly obvious step that I might be missing here, that might account for the issue?  Are there some other ranges that I should be blocking instead, maybe?  Or maybe I just need to wait longer for the change to propagate before it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BitTorrent can be very difficult to block completely, due to the different ports various clients can use. Attempting to block it based purely on the ports it uses is a bit futile, unfortunately. The page you've linked to is for the original BitTorrent client, and won't cover the multitude of BitTorrent clients that are out there now.

To be honest, the best way to block it, if it's absolutely essential, is to block all outbound access and just allow through the protocols you need. Other than that, without some kind of clever packet inspection, you're only going to get frustrated.

Sorry I couldn't offer any better advice!

Comment: Take a look at a 7-layer inspection/enforcement device, Packeteer, Palo Alto, but it's going to cost you.

Comment: +1 bittorrent can go via pretty much any port, only way to block it is to deny everything other than what you need or get a router that supports P2P filtering... but encryption can get round that. Hard one...

Comment: Late to the party, disable UPNP in the router, this way the BT client cannot automatically configure port forwarding, then set a good password on the router. Not 100% but will make downloading with BT painfully slow if not useless. Be sure to delete any ports forwarded already.